# Cut + Paste behavior of folders in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, copy-paste, directory

I couldn't found any questions under `Windows 8.1` tag, So I'm worried whether these kinds of questions can be asked here. Since my query is not related to programmatic. it a general query.

I have folder named "**TestFolder**" which contains four sub folders in it, they are **A**, **B**, **C** and **D**.

Then using `ctrl + A` shortcut key combination, i have selected all the folders in it.

Then i have unselected the folder **C** alone.,

using the key combination `ctrl + x`, i have cut those folders.

So all the folder icons except **C** will become `disabled state`. right?(I hope you followed me on that one, refer the below image)

[image]

Then creating a new folder in "TestFolder". i guess the created folder icon should not be in `disabled state`, but it is.If that is the behavior of MS Windows, why?

Answer (score 1):

The created folder may look to you as disabled but actually it is not. Try pasting the other folders(which you have cut) in the other location and you can see the difference that your folder(newly created one) is not disabled.

Comment: Yeah, the paste functionality works fine, but my question is about the look and feel of newly created folder.

Comment: According to me after refreshing the windows explorer the look and feel is like any other normal folder.

Comment: but it should display correctly, before it is refreshed, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right Joy.This is what I have also eXperienced with windows 8 that's why I was able to tell you that after refreshing it appears normal. Ideally it should appear disabled.